# RAML resourceTypes and traits VS Swagger $ref

Tags: swagger, raml

I really like how RAML focuses on reducing the amount of duplication and increasing consistency across APIs with the use of ResourceTypes and Traits.

But after taking a closer look at the Swagger spec, it appears that you can accomplish the same thing by using $ref.

Is there an advantage to RAML over $ref in this scenario? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

After I looked into more this, I have a better understanding on how this works.

One big difference is that ResourceTypes in RAML accept parameters, which enables more code to be extracted.

Also, it is limited where you can use $ref in swagger. Meaning, you cannot apply $ref at the resource level or on http methods. Examples of things you can externalize are parameters, responses and models.

ResourceTypes and Traits are more powerful in externalizing common patterns in REST  and re-using them across different services

Comment: I'm using traits for defining multiple headers specification in RAML. I've got several headers that are reused across lots of resources. Now I'm trying to switch from RAML to swagger. Copying inline header definitions seems a complete overkill to me. Do you know if I can reuse traits for headers in swagger?